# How to troubleshoot printing to multiple printers connected via USB in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, printing, printer

I have two printers (one Canon, one Brother) attached to my home computer. Both printers are directly plugged in via individual USB cables. After printing to one printer, if I print to the other one, I get one of two problems:

- printer appears offline and cannot be set to online
- the job gets sent to the wrong printer, which prints endless blank pages

All I need to do to solve the problem is disconnect the USB cable of the printer I want to print to, and then reconnect it. This works every time.

After a few months of doing this, I'd really like to make it easier to do. Neither printer has network capabilities, meaning USB is the only way to go.

1. What should I do to find the root cause of this issue?
2. If it's not possible to solve the root cause, would it be possible to have a small batch file which I can click to emulate unplugging and replugging the printer?

I have tried:

- updating the drivers for both printers
- setting both printers to 'isolation mode'
- checking that the printers are located on different USB ports in printer properties. This appears to be the case:

[image: Printer Properties]

Neither have helped.

Comment: Are these printers plugged directly in to the computer? Have you tried updating all the drivers for the printers and computers? You can also force the printers to run in isolation mode so they can’t affect each other: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/printer-driver-isolation try changing both to `isolated` mode.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you! I'm on the road this week but will try what you've suggested when I get back, and will report back.

Comment: @Appleoddity Both printers are directly plugged in via individual USB cables. I've updated both printer drivers, and Windows 10 is always up-to-date. I've set both drivers to isolation mode and restarted the machine: no difference.

Comment: Ok. Go in to the printer properties on each. Check the ports. By some chance are both printers connected to the same port? It should say something like USB001:.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help! They appear to be on different ports. One is Port_#008.Hub_#003, and the other is Port_#0004.Hub_#0006. I'll add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Those are funny USB ports. Usually port names are like USB001, etc. Are the printers connected to the PC via a hub? In that case try plugging them directly into the PC.

Comment: They are plugged directly into the PC, not via a hub.